# Code to identify element by selenium

Tags: selenium

When I inspect an element with firebug it is displayed like this:

```
<a onclick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create new challenge</a>
```

For this I have written code using Xpath, Href to identify elements.
But `Webdriver` is failing to identify element.

Can any of you suggest me please how to write a code in python to identify that elements?

Comment: when i inspect element with firebug displayed as < a onclcick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create new challenge</a>

Answer (score 2):

Try using xpath `"//a[text()='Create new challenge')]"`

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend not using the route that YuvarajHK had gone.  Xpath is much [slower and much less readable than CSS](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

Instead, use CSS.  So the issue here is, there is not really an attribute that you can match one.  it wouldn't be smart to match on `onclick` or the `href`, so you only have one option when it comes to CSS.  An option that i **highly recommend**...

Use Parent-child hierarchy to uniquely identify your element.

So, your element has a parent. Instead of taking the xpath given in the other answer which is very inefficient to match on text, find the parent of that particular element.

Consider the following:

```
<div id="newChallenge">
  ...
  <a onclick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create new challenge</a>
  ...
</div>
```

So the first step would be to find the parent of the elemnt. If the parent of the element doesn't have an ID, that's ok.  Just go up another level.

*In our case:*  Our parent selector would be `div#newChallenge` and the selector for our link, would simply be `a`.

Our CSS Selector would be

```
div#newChallenge a
```

(or)

```
div#newChallenge > a
```

(depending on if the `a` is a descendant-of rather than child-of)

Furthermore, if you have multiple links:

```
<div id="newChallenge">
  <a href="someOtherPage.html">Hi</a>
  <a onclick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create new challenge</a>
  <a onclick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create something else</a>
</div>
```

You can see that our selector `div#newChallenge a` would not uniquely identify our element.   So instead, lets find the index of the link.  In this case, the index of the link we want to select is `2` because...

```
<div id="newChallenge">
     (1)  <a href="someOtherPage.html">Hi</a>
  -> (2)  <a onclick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create new challenge</a>
     (3)  <a onclick="viewmodel.view_results(false);" href="#">Create something else</a>
</div>
```

Then, we could just append the CSS pseudo-class `:nth-of-type` (or even other `:nth-*` pseudo-classes)

Your final selector could be

```
div#newChallenge a:nth-of-type(2)
```

**So to conclude**: The code that you would use to find the element in *python* would be:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#newChallenge a:nth-of-type(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

css=a[onclick*='viewmodel.view_results(false)']

Please Let me know Is the above CSS Selector is working or NOT.